# Problem adding new locale / Resaving matrix blocks Failed / Table 'matrixcontent_files' doesn't exist

Tags: localization, error

I've got an error message from my craft (2.6.2990) after adding a German locale:

> Resaving all localizable elements: Failed
>
> Resaving matrix blocks: Failed

in the sidebar and here is what I found in craft logs:

`` 2017/09/20 14:52:13 [error] [system.db.CDbCommand] CDbCommand::fetchAll() failed: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'zg_blike.craft_matrixcontent_files' doesn't exist. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT `elements`.`id`, `elements`.`type`, `elements`.`enabled`, `elements`.`archived`, `elements`.`dateCreated`, `elements`.`dateUpdated`, `elements_i18n`.`slug`, `elements_i18n`.`uri`, `elements_i18n`.`enabled` AS `localeEnabled`, `content`.`id` AS `contentId`, `matrixblocks`.`fieldId`, `matrixblocks`.`ownerId`, `matrixblocks`.`ownerLocale`, `matrixblocks`.`typeId`, `matrixblocks`.`sortOrder` ``

I checked the DB and of course did not find table called `craft_matrixcontent_files`, instead only `craft_matrixcontent_file`

Any ideas?

Comment: Forgot to mention: I'm using Craft Pro with Commerce installed

Comment: Sounds like there are some consistency problem in your database.  Are all of Craft's foreign keys in place between tables? We've seen it happen semi-frequently where someone restores a database backup to a MySQL box that only supports the MyISAM storage engine and it will silently drop all foreign keys causing data to get really out of sync.

Comment: It's very hard to say for me if ALL of the keys are there, but they _seem_ to be fine: phpmyadmin's designer shows connections between tables, InnoDB is supported (all tables except `searchindex`).

Comment: Someone manually edited the database maybe? Does the `craft_fields` table have a row with a "files" that's of type "Matrix"?

Comment: Thank you all for suggestions. At the end I have no idea what the problem exactly was, but I could solve it by renaming a table called `matrxicontent_file` to `matrixcontent_files`. For sure nobody edited the database, since I'm the only one who worked on it (except I do some things unconsciously). I also found something that can be related: There is an entry with a handle `files` which belongs to `global` context and another one with a handle `file` which belongs to `matrixBlockType`. I also tried to delete all the matrix fields from the CP and these strange ones manually. Did not help.

Comment: Super weird... would you mind adding that as an official answer?  There's a small chance it might help someone in the future. :)

Comment: Ups, sorry. It broke at the end. It does not work. Still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a field called `files`, it did not belong to matrix. After deleting it (tried also simply renaming), the problem disappeared.

After that I created a field with the same name and that did not cause any problems.

Still do not know the exact reason, but later will have time dig a bit deeper, so if get some results will post them.